# Regex.Matches returns empty result

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to filter some forum entry content out of a forum page. The forum entries are located between two blockquote elements (as seen in the Regex). I want to filter the content out with a Regex. This is the code I'm using:

```
string pattern = @"(<blockquote class=\"postcontent restore \">)(.*?)(</blockquote>)";
Regex test = new Regex(pattern,  RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
MatchCollection m = test.Matches(downloadString);
var arr = m
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(n => n.Value)
  .ToArray();

foreach (string match in arr)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(match);
    }
Console.ReadLine();
```

I have this sample for example:

```
<blockquote class="postcontent restore ">
  <br>
    Some Stuff
  <br>
    Some Stuff #2
  <br>
</blockquote>
```

The problem I got is that the returned array is empty. Any idea what could be wrong? I guess it's because of the whitespaces but I have no idea how to "ignore" them.

Comment: `Dot in your regex won't match line breaks.`

Comment: `@"(?s)(<blockquote class=""postcontent restore\s*"">)(.*?)(</blockquote>)"`

Comment: If you use `RegexOptions.Singleline`, you will perhaps be able to use it a bit, but only an HTML parser can really help you. If the text inside blockquote is very long, your lazy dot matching will cause a backtracking buffer overflow or whatever it is called.

Comment: Updated my answer with a tested source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

. matches any character except new line.

You can use this to include line breaks:

```
(<blockquote class=\"postcontent restore \">)(\n*.*)(<\/blockquote>)
```

Your pattern also did not use escapes for double qoute and forward slashes so here it is:

EDIT: Sorry. @ is there, so the final version should be:)
EDIT 2: Full tested source code. It is your responsibility to check for IsMatch or null references

```
string pattern = @"(<blockquote class=\""postcontent restore \"">)+((\n*)(.*))+(</blockquote>)";
Regex test = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = test.Matches(downloadString);
StringBuilder xmlContentBUilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Capture capture in matches[0].Groups[2].Captures)
{
    xmlContentBUilder.Append(capture);
}
Console.WriteLine(xmlContentBUilder);
```

Comment: Mhh, that seems to have the same outcome.

Comment: @BitteWenden Sorry. Could not tested that time.